# Язык плагина при include_once

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемкой на Wordpress, что при инклуде плагина в тему или другой плагин язык такого плагина меняется на английский.

Плагин добавляю через include_once:

```
include_once(get_template_directory() . '/plugins/plugin_name/plugin_name.php');
```

В работе таких плагинов проблем нет, кроме смены языка.

Может кто сталкивался с этим и подскажет решение? Любой костыль или идея тоже пригодятся.

Answer (score 0):

Естественно. Потому что вы рушите систему переводов WordPress.

Как она работает? Во время инициализации (при каждом обращении к сайту) WordPress проверяет по своей базе, какие плагины у него активированы, загружает их и вызывает действие `plugins_loaded` (на самом деле еще ряд других, но нам это неважно сейчас). Плагин должен иметь свой хук на это действие и в нём вызвать функцию `load_plugin_textdomain()`, в которой третьим параметром указать папку, где лежат файлы переводов .mo, обычно это относительный путь от папки самого плагина.

Что происходит, когда вы совершаете насилие над WordPress, сказать сложно. Если плагинов вообще нет, то действие `plugins_loaded` может и не вызываться вообще. Если они есть, то, возможно, это действие вызывается WordPress раньше, чем выполняется ваш include_once. А если даже и позже, и в плагине срабатывает хук, то возможны проблемы с указанием относительного пути к файлам перевода.

Кроме того, при загрузке плагинов выполняется еще ряд других действий, которые отрабатываются хуками в плагинах и самым критическим образом влияют на функциональность. И потеря системы переводов - только одна из возможных проблем. Через include_once будут работать только самые примитивные плагины. Попробуйте так подключить WooCommerce, например, и посмотрите, что получится.

Многие плагины выполняют ряд действий при активации/деактивации, установке и удалению. Например, создают/удаляют свои таблицы в базе данных или записывают свои данные с общие таблицы. Отрубая этот механизм, вы легко можете получить разрушенную базу данных WP.

А самое непонятное - вот для чего всё это? Для мифической производительности? Правильно настроенный сервер с WordPress может выдержать до [10,000 соединений в секунду](https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/).

В общем, не ломайте систему, делайте всё как положено - сэкономите массу времени на поиске очередных косяков.